# PHP: Problems using strtotime

Tags: php

I want to filter my output:

```
07-02-13 20:08:41   test11@gmail.com
07-02-13 20:09:41   test11@gmail.com
07-02-13 20:21:25   hottie@gmail.com
07-02-13 20:56:51   ugly@gmail.com
07-02-13 21:42:37   selma532@gmail.com
07-02-13 22:09:11   blalbla421@gmail.com
```

I want to filter my output, so emails there appearing within 2 minutes has to do something. This is my "filter code" so far. But it is not working. What am i doing wrong?

```
strtotime('-2 minutes"', strtotime(date('d-m-y H:i:s', $filter['created'])
```

Comment: What is `$filter['created']`? If it contains timestamp, why are you formating it to ambigous date fromat just to turn it back into timestamp and substract 2 minutes? What is not working? Code you posted does not attempt to filter anything...

Comment: I was having trouble with this as well.  I was taking a date in the format of MM-DD-YYYY and I created a function [ that I called rolex() :) ] and this used strtotime to get a unix timestamp that I used to remove the 0s from the front of the MM and DD [ date('n-j-Y', $d_string); ]...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you date format is ambiguous. Does `07-02-13` mean February 7th 2013 (ie today) or does it mean July 2nd 2013 (US standard format), or does it mean February 13th 2007 (big-endian format) or what?

I would suggest rewriting your code so that it produces timestamps in big-endian format,
that is `Y-m-d H:i:s`. In this format, you can compare them as if they were strings, so all you'd have to do is:

```
$two_minutes_ago = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("-2 minutes"));
if( $value_to_test > $two_mintes_ago) {
    do_something();
}
```

Comment: I tried your way, but it did not work. Is not filtering what I posted on top